# Trying to Initiate a PSTN call returns "Call source identity invalid"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

#### EDIT: This question has now got a little attention here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/287517/trying-to-call-pstn-phone-from-bot-using-post-requ.html

#### Hello there,

As you can tell from my reputation, this is actually only my second post. I've been through Google to find a solution, or to see if someone else have had the same issue. So here goes

### PSTN Call issue (http Post request)

I'm trying to make a Azure bot call a PSTN number. using this example: [Create peer-to-peer PSTN call with application hosted media](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-10-create-peer-to-peer-pstn-call-with-application-hosted-media) from the [Cloud communications part of the MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/communications-api-overview?view=graph-rest-beta)

But the request yields a: **Call source identity invalid.** .

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "7507",
        "message": "Call source identity invalid.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-02-12T13:10:07",
            "request-id": "2032222f-84b9-4906-bb37-ec938d29ec45",
            "client-request-id": "2032222f-84b9-4906-bb37-ec938d29ec45"
        }
    }
}
```

**I have made a detailed explanation in my GitRepo [here](https://github.com/lund76/teams-pstn-poc/blob/main/PSTN-Call-Issue.md)**

Needless to say, that any input is greatly appreciated

Best regard
Søren

Comment: From the Github repo shared, the UPN with which the app is created is different from the one used to assign the phone number, would you confirm whether the PSTN number has been added to the correct application instance ?

Comment: Hi @Diana .
Thanks for pointing that out. And your're right. I missed the second instance of the UPN when trying to anonymize the example. I can confirm, that the phonenumber has indeed been added to the correct application instance. The Github repo has been updated with screenshot from teams admin.

Comment: Is your issue resolved now? @Goonie

Comment: Hello @Saonti-MSFT. I have updated this post with a link to a Q/A where someone has replied they will look into it

Answer (score 0):

Just faced this issue and was fixed as follows:

Check if the ApplicationId in teams app instance has the same ApplicationId from your bot registered in Bot Services:

Using teams powershell module: Get-CSOnlineApplicationInstance

If needed, you update it using Set-CsOnlineApplicationInstance -ApplicationId `<AppId from bot>`

Also, make sure that the applicationInstance.Id in the request body is the applicationInstance.objectId from teams application instance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. The user account created with New-CsOnlineApplicationInstance didn't seem to work, so I manually created one in the Teams Resource accounts admin centre, and used Set-CsOnlineApplicationInstance to point at that one instead, which seemed to do the trick.